# google sheets week/year array formula

Tags: google-sheets, charts, array-formulas

I have **sheet1** that looks like this:

[image]

and **sheet2** looks like this:

**ColA:**
=UNIQUE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({"Week/Year";arrayformula(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A$2:A);"";CONCAT(CONCAT(WEEKNUM(Sheet1!A$2:A;2);"/");TEXT(Sheet1!A$2:A;"YY"))))};COUNTA(Sheet1!A$2:A);1))

**ColB:**
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet1!B$2:B; ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKNUM(Sheet1!A$2:A;2)=index(SPLIT(A2;"/");0;1)))) ***<--I need help here***

[image]

A **chart** is built on the basis of sheet2:

[image]

I need to get the sum of values from column B if the week number and year are the same as column A (Column A is date format dd.mm.yyyy). I managed to filter the amount by week number, but I can't add a second check for the year. Please help me, I've already tried everything.

Sheet example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XjJLOC5NHZwKirxbxZQzPAzpU8nCvhNs2_M323rZf3U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Solution amended for locale formula and to sort the weeknum properly. See `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XjJLOC5NHZwKirxbxZQzPAzpU8nCvhNs2_M323rZf3U/edit#gid=1634886610&range=F1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need (cell `A1`)? Delete the values in column `B`.

`=arrayformula(query(query({Sheet1!A:B\if(Sheet1!A:A<>"";{weeknum(Sheet1!A:A;2)&"/"&right(year(Sheet1!A:A);2)\year(Sheet1!A:A)&"-"&text(weeknum(Sheet1!A:A;2);"00")};)};"select Col4,Col3,sum(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col4,Col3 label Col3 'Date', sum(Col2) 'Value' ";1);"select Col2,Col3";1))`

**Notes:**

I use an array `{}` to get the following 4 columns:

Col1 and Col2: `Sheet1!A:B`

Col3: `weeknum(Sheet1!A:A;2)&"/"&right(year(Sheet1!A:A);2)` (eg. n/yy)

Col4: `year(Sheet1!A:A)&"-"&text(weeknum(Sheet1!A:A;2);"00")` (eg. yyyy-nn)

Col3 and Col4 only return a value whilst there are values down column A: `if(Sheet1!A:A<>"";`

Col3 is the weeknum and year displayed in your graph.

Col4 is the same but formatted differently for the sort.

The first `query` gets Col4,Col3 and the sum of Col2, then the second query gets Col3 and sum(Col2).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I needed!

Comment: I think headers should be 0, because we are losing the very first week